# Read from file split content into group when empty line

Tags: c#, file

I´m reading a file in my C# code.

The file looks like this:

```
13 
56
89

55
66

9

58
```

I´m trying to read the file and split the numbers up in different variabels.
Want it look like this:

```
numb1 = 13,56,89
numb2 = 55,66
numb3 = 9
numb4 = 58
```

When it is a blank line I want to split it up and group numbers together. But I don´t know how to do.

My code so far:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InputReader inputReader = new InputReader();

        var file =File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\forsb\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Input\numberlist.txt");

        string[] a = new string[] { };

        foreach (var item in file)
        {
            a = item.Split(new string[] { "\r\n\r\n" },
                           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        }
          


        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: Show us the code you've written so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code

```
    public static void Main()
{
    var fileName = "filename.txt";
    // CREATE a file in your Sandbox using .NET Fiddle 
    WriteFile(fileName);

    string line;  
    var str="";

    // Read the file and display it line by line.  
    System.IO.StreamReader file =
        new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);  
    while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)  
    {  
        line = line.Trim();
        //if line is empty
        //show total values until now
        if (line == "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            str="";
            continue;
        }
        else
        {     
            //if first element, add here
            if(str != "")
            {
              str=str+","+line;
            }
            else
            {
                str=line;
            }
            
        }
            
    }  
    
    //for remaining last line
    Console.WriteLine(str);

    file.Close();  
}

public static void WriteFile(string path)
{
   File.WriteAllText(path, "13\n56\n89\n\n\n\n55\n66\n\n\n\n9\n58");
}
```

I have used the sample code in fiddle looks working.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/hOFSi2

basically, i am trying to read here line by line, if line is empty and there is some data saved in "str" print it, else continue

Note: You don't need to create file using "WriteFile" function, I have created it in fiddle, so adding code here for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a `List<List<int>>` to hold your sets of numbers.  Then you can do whatever you want with them.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    
    String fileName = @"C:\Users\forsb\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Input\numberlist.txt";
    List<List<int>> numberSets = new List<List<int>>();

    // Read the file and collect the numbers in "curSet" until a blank line is encountered
    List<int> curSet = new List<int>();    
    foreach (String line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(fileName))
    {
        if (line.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            // blank line found, add the current set of numbers to our list,
            // but only if the current set actually has any numbers in it.
            if (curSet.Count > 0)
            {
                numberSets.Add(curSet);
                curSet = new List<int>();
            }               
        }
        else
        {
            int number;
            if (int.TryParse(line, out number))
            {
                curSet.Add(number);
            }
        }
    }
    // end of file reached, add a pending set of numbers if it exists
    if (curSet.Count > 0)
    {
        numberSets.Add(curSet);
    }

    // do something with the collection of number lists:
    for(int i=0; i<numberSets.Count; i++)
    {
        List<int> numberSet = numberSets[i];
        // ... do something with "numberSet" ...
        Console.WriteLine(i + ": " + String.Join(",", numberSet));
    }

    Console.Write("Press Enter to Quit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output on my system:

```
0: 13,56,89
1: 55,66
2: 9
3: 58
Press Enter to Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the split for each row that you read from the file. You need to do the split for the complete content of the file.

Code below will give the output you want.

> ```
> a[0] = 13,56,89
> a[1] = 55,66
> a[2] = 9
> a[3] = 58
> ```

```
var data = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\forsb\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Input\numberlist.txt");
string[] a = data.Split("\r\n\r\n", System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

for(int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
{
    a[i] = a[i].Replace("\r\n", ",");
}
```